# Are questions about contacting a service's support staff on topic? Too localized?

Tags: discussion, scope

From Web Applications newsletter, I have seen [LibraryThing: How do I tell the bug collectors that the site is completely broken?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24188/librarything-how-do-i-tell-the-bug-collectors-that-the-site-is-completely-broken) This question is on new top questions.

The question is about how to contact site admin.

Do you think this sort question should be allowed?

Aren't they too localized, not of help to future visitors?

Answer (score 6):

It depends.

I haven't checked, but if how to contact the site owners isn't obvious on a site then asking it here *will* help future visitors.

I'd be the first to admit that it looks like it should be too localised.

Answer (score 4):

It is too localised and voted as such. It's about how to contact the site while they were doing some tests or debugging.

After reading the answers from two developers on the LibraryThing, it's even more so too localised to their downtime event.